# window.open not work inside cjuidialog yii1

Tags: php, yii, window.open, yii1.x, cjuidialog

i want open new tab after save in cjuidialog. i used

```
window.top.location.href
```

its work but not open new tab but if i used

```
window.open('https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+62878787811423&text=Tesdawks', '_blank');
```

it doesnt work.
this my full code

```
<?php $this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog', array(
        'id'=>'cru-dialog',
        'options'=>array(
            'title'=>'Detail view',
            'autoOpen'=>false,
            'modal'=>true,
            'width'=>'80%',
            'height'=>450,
            'close'=>'js:function(){
                $("#cru-frame").attr("src","");
                $.fn.yiiGridView.update("indexKonsumen-grid", {
                    data: $(this).serialize()
                });
            }',
        ),
    ));
?>

<iframe id="cru-frame" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

my controller

```
if(isset($_POST['wa'])){
                    echo CHtml::script("window.parent.$('#cru-dialog').dialog('close');
                                        window.parent.$('#cru-frame').attr('src','');
                                        window.open('https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+62878787811423&text=Tesdawks', '_blank');
                    ");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried just `window.open('https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+6287878711423&text=Tesdawks')` without including the `_blank` target? Does this create any redirect?

Comment: wow you saved my life @Skully . remove `_blank` and 100% work. Thank you

Comment: Glad it solved it, I have posted an answer with some more clarification for anyone else who might stumble upon this issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter for `window.open()` is the windowName, you appear to be using it in the context of trying to open a new tab by providing a target as `_blank`, however the default behaviour for `window.open` is to open the window in a new tab, so this is redundant.

```js
if(isset($_POST['wa'])) {
    echo CHtml::script("window.parent.$('#cru-dialog').dialog('close');
    window.parent.$('#cru-frame').attr('src','');
    window.open('https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+62878787811423&text=Tesdawks');
");
}
```